# Uploading files into hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop

I've recently downloaded Oracle Virtual Box and I want to take some data and import it into HDFS. I want to state that I am a complete novice when it comes to these things. I've tried copying the instructions from a udacity course which do NOT work.

I apologize if the terminology I'm using is not accurate.

So in my VM space I have the following files

1. Computer
2. Training's Home (Provided by Udacity)
3. Eclipse
4. Trash

Inside Training's Home I have on the left-hand side under Places

1. training,
2. Desktop
3. File System
4. Network
5. Trash
6. Documents
7. Pictures
8. Downloads

On the right-hand side when I select training there are many folders one of them is udacity_training. When I select this there are two folders
code and data. When I select data there are further two folders something called access_log.gz and purchases.txt which is the data I want to load into HDFS

Copying the command entered by the udacity tutorial I typed

[training@localhost ~]$ ls *access_log.gz* *purchases.txt*

This gave the error messages

ls: cannot access access_log.gz: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access purchases: No such file or directory

I then tried the next line just to see what happens which was

```
[training@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls
[training@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -put purchases.txt
```

again an error saying

```
put: 'purchases.txt': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't really understand command line prompts I think they're in Linux? So what I'm typing looks quite Alien to me. I want to be able to understand what I'm typing. Could someone help me access the data and perhaps also provide some info on where I can understand what I'm actually typing into the command line? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `put` command requires the local file(s) and remote directory arguments, check here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put . If you want to put it to the file system root directory, use `/` to indicate as the remote directory argument.

Comment: sorry where would the / go? Can you give me an example of what to type?

Comment: Assuming that your shell is already in the directory where the `purchases.txt` file on the local machine is: `hadoop fs -put purchases.txt /`, otherwise it should look like: `hadoop fs -put /some/path/on/local/machine/purchases.txt /`

Comment: Ok thanks how would i get my shell to the directory where purchases.txt is in if it was not?

Answer (score 1):

Please start learning the basics of [linux](https://diyhacking.com/linux-commands-for-beginners/) & [hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) commands.
To answer your question try below options.

> Use command ***cd /dir_name*** to goto the required directory and then use
>    ***hadoop fs -put /file_name /hdfs/path***

Comment: Thank you, i've been learning some basic linux commands to start with. When i tried hadoop fs -put /file_name /hdfs/path. Now that i know some basics i did cd udacity_training/data which contains the document purchases.txt which i want to load to HDFS. However when i type hadoop fs -put/purchases.txt/hdfs/path i get an unknown command

Comment: Try with spaces hadoop fs -put  <linux source path>  <hdfs path>

Comment: sorry could you elaborate on what <linux source path> and <hdfs path> are?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether hadoop is installed on my VM? If i type hadoop fs -ls i get the following error i won't type it in full

ls: Invalid host name: local host is: "java.net.UnknownHostException.....